# Angularjs not working in windows chrome and firefox after writing own code

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Below are two scenario for problem:

1) The issue is I'm facing is if I write some answer at here and I want to add demo example for `angularjs` using  snippet. When I add proper working code for angularjs, includig script file on snippet and press run. Nothing is working. No console error. Everything is loaded including angularjs script file.

Now if I add that snippet into my answer and check it in my laptop, it's working fine or if I check my own answer after reloading that page, snippet is  working fine which was not working when I try to write some code on snippet for answer.

Same thing happen when creating fiddle.

2) [Link for Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18427/)

If I try to open above fiddle link in new tab then fiddle is working fine.

But problem is **If I copy same code from fiddle and create new fiddle with same code, add `angularjs` script and try to run it, it's not binding scope value to html and return below output**

```
If you change the value with the arrows ng-change doesn't work on the first change. [SHOW ONE DROPDOWN WITH NO OPTION]  {{selected}}
```

**Question**: How I can solve this problem and make angularjs up and running?

Comment: looks normal behavior to me?

Comment: Not at all for me...:)

Comment: everything seems OK..fiddle works fine...can't actually get your point

Comment: what does this have to do with the browsers, or windows-8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and the solution is by adding `ng-app` in starting of div/html makes my example working which I was always not adding. It is working in fiddle and in snippet also.

In question's fiddle, there is default `ng-app` already added so working that fiddle working fine but by creating new fiddle `ng-app` will not added by default so not working but by adding it manually it's working fine.

```js
var application = angular.module('myApp', []);
application.controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = 'It\'s Working ';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    {{myData}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like AngularJS library is not loaded in your environment. Make sure you have included it in the `body` of your HTML page.

Also regarding the problem in your jsFiddle which doesn't work when you copy paste an existing working fiddle, you need to select the proper library and to change its loading behavior from `onLoad` to `No-wrap - in <body>`. When you click on a working fiddle it works, because these preferences are pre-loaded. When you create a new one, you probably don't change the default, which `onLoad`.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tried given `src` of angular in external library or in html part in jsfiddle...But my bad luck..it's not working...

Comment: Ok, lets try to rule out it is not library loading issue. Copy and paste the code from your jsFiddle into a new jsFiddle window. In the new window, there will be two drop down `select` elements on the top left pane. Pick `AngularJS 1.2` from the first drop down, and `No-wrap - in <body>` from the second drop down. Now try to run the program. If it doesn't work like the original jsFiddle, there must be something else going on. Use the same http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/18427/ jsFiddle so we are on the same page.

Comment: [Images](http://imgur.com/a/oRplO)..I have tried you suggestion but not working..I thinking same that the problem is related to something else...May be OS..Check images of jsfiddle

Comment: That is weird. I would also go to Chrome's dev tools and look at my "Networks" tab to see if the required JS files are loaded, just in case some network issue not loading your JS files. Still looks like Angular not detected/loaded in the browser. Have you tried testing locally with a local copy of angular library?

Comment: I have tried to check network tabs to check whether required file are fetched or not. Also checked from source tab in Chrome dev tools and angular js file is located. Make a break point in angularjs variable and it is actually called but somehow functionality are not working...